# In Power BI, Data source setting is not worked out while changing DB

Tags: powerbi-desktop, powerbi-datasource

As of now I have done by using 'Advanced Editor' option, for each table. I need to change the DB for the whole project itself.

data is in cloud only.

please post your solution

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

From `File`->`Options and settings`->`Data source settings` click `Change Source...` button and enter new values for `Server` and `Database`.

Comment: Thanks Andrey. I tried on the same way only. But it is not updating. It is again pointing out the old DB only.